# Angular 2 (4.0.0) Dart transformers not work - Unsupported operation: Using the 'angular2' transformer is required

Tags: angular, dart

Dart - 1.24.2

Angular - 4.0.0

Chromium - 45.0.2454.104

pubspec.yaml

```
name: Test
description: A web app that uses AngularDart Components
version: 0.0.1
#homepage: https://www.example.com
#author: serhii <email@example.com>

environment:
sdk: '>=1.24.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: ^4.0.0
  angular_components: ^0.8.0

dev_dependencies:
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1

transformers:
- angular:
   entry_points:
      - web/applications/courier/courier.dart

- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

Chromium output:

```
package:angular/src/platform/bootstrap.dart:107 
Exception: Unsupported  operation: Using the 'angular2' transformer is required.      
Please see https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/tutorial for setup  instructions,
and ensure your 'pubspec.yaml' file is configured to invoke the 'angular2'
transformer on your application's entry point.
```

If i build this - all is ok, if i serve this (`pub serve`) - all is ok but i need it to work in Chromium. Please help!

Comment: what do you get when you run `pub build`? How are you loading it using Chromium and from where? With Chromium, do you mean Dartium (Chromium shipped with Dart) or actually Chromium?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue in Dartium (all the same versions mentioned above).

Comment: Same issue for me, I just downloaded the latest dartium Version 50.0.2661.108 (64-bit) on mac

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your entrypoint parameter is correct (path and file):

```
transformers:
- angular:
   entry_points:
      - web/applications/courier/courier.dart
```

Had the very same error after renaming my entry_point file and didn't update pubspec.yaml.